# GNOME 3 16.04 LTS Unstable Battery Life

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, gnome, power-management, battery

So I have a new Dell XPS 15" with a 97 wH battery, a 4k display and a NVIDIA GTX 1050. I installed GNOME 3 as my flavor of UBUNTU (16.04 LTS). In addition I added the `nvidia-prime` driver and `tlp`.

All together I get a battery life indicator which is widely inconsistent. Let's say I have selected to use my Intel GPU for the moment (and dimmed my 4k display to the lowest brightness). Then on a full charge my battery indicator estimates a time of 9 hours. Amazing! Then it immediately drops to 2 hours (realistic), then I open Google Chrome to post this question and we are back at 8 hours. And right now (maybe 3 minutes into typing this) we are at 7 hours. Checked it again and it is 4 hours. Just checked once more back at 6 hours.

So besides from me naturally wanting to have a computer with 9 hours of battery life, I would at least like an accurate and consistent read.

I have tried to take screen shots but I cant keep the battery drop down open and use my hotkey for some reason...

Comment: Run your battery all the way down until the laptop powers off. Recharge the battery, and see if the battery life indicator gives better results.

Comment: @heynnema ok, I shall try this

Comment: @heynnema this has not changed the jumping battery life.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB **17.04** and see how the battery indicator works.

Comment: @heynnema prior to doing this I am just curious as to what is different in 17.04. I chose to use 16.04 because of LTS...

Comment: Support for newer hardware and bug fixes.